How can I use the word 魅力的?
The range of translation for this word is charming, fascinating or attractive.  These are very different words in English.  I want to describe a small village as 'charming' and I think the word 魅力的　would work.  Would it also work to describe a person as charming?

The core element might become clearer when you think about the verbs "to charm," "to fascinate", "to attract." They're all about pulling attention toward something. It's true that these English adjectives often aren't interchangeable though.

魅力的 is a very general word, and I would say it's closest to "attractive" or "appealing". It doesn't say anything regarding the type of the attractiveness.
While "charming village" may be associated with certain friendly, warm or old-fashioned atmosphere, 魅力的 does not carry such connotations. For example, a village with a large modern supermarket and a decent hospital is certainly 魅力的 to the locals, but this may not be described as "charming" or "fascinating".
魅力的 is also very commonly used to describe a person, and it doesn't specify why he/she is appealing. Depending on the context, it can be used in relation to their business skills, sexual appeal, personality, wealth, or anything.

What an awesome explanation. Can you think of a word that would be equivalent to the use of charming in English?  For the whimsical old-fashioned atmosphere as well as the endearing attractive  loveliness of a person?

@momijiblossom のどか(な) and 風情がある are relatively specific expressions, but they are common phrases to describe a village, and may convey the atmosphere suggested by "charming (village)".
